# SQL: Improve Select Query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, razor, sql-server-ce

I have reasons to believe that this code can be done much better, and probably doing much more of the work with the query to begin with?

I'll try to explain this.

Each row on my database has either a 1, 2 or 3 value for `exercise`, and then also a number as `rep` that could be any number, but in this code I choose to only care for 1-12, so this code selects the row that has the highest value of `kilograms` (which is a column and has a value on each row) where `exercise` is 1 and `rep` is 1, and then 2 and 3 etc. etc. up to 12, then changes `exercise` to 2 and goes from 1-12 again selecting the top `kilograms` row.

Does this make sense?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (var ii = 1; ii <= 12; ii++) {
        var getPR = "SELECT top 1 kg, rep, date FROM Test WHERE exerVariName = 'Comp' AND exercise = @0 AND rep = @1 order by kg desc";
        db.Execute(getPR, i, ii);
        foreach (var get in db.Query(getPR, i, ii)) {
            DateTime Date = get.Date;
            var finalDate = Date.ToString("MMM d, yyyy");
            var weight = get.kg + "kg";
            var reps = "x " + get.rep;
            <a>@weight @reps - @finalDate</a>
            <br>
        }
    }
}
```

I use SQL Server Compact, and it's not a MVC project.

Comment: Please don't say this is part of cshtml file?

Comment: Why not? @trailmax

Comment: Razor files are made for applying view model data into HTML markup. DB requests should live in controller and pass a view model with the data. (Assuming MVC)

Comment: Duh.. I've read the last line. Sorry, my bad. Should not skim questions.

Comment: Ye, im not doing a MVC project, that was all too complicated, never found a good tutorial for it, but I'll try to learn about it later, it's somewhat hard to find help for my problems I run into since most questions on here are in "MVC format" when it comes to razor @trailmax

Comment: There is a free video course: https://app.pluralsight.com/player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m1-intro&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building It is for MVC4, but basic principles are unchanged going into MVC5. Also this official tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/index if you prefer to read rather than video.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all rows you are interested in with only one query using `Group By` and `MAX` aggregated function.

```
SELECT t.kg, t.rep, t.date
FROM Test t
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX(kg) as kg, exercise, rep
    FROM Test
    WHERE exerVariName = 'Comp'
    GROUP BY exercise, rep) i
ON t.exercise = i.exercise AND t.rep = i.rep AND t.kg = i.kg
WHERE t.exerVariName = 'Comp'
```

Inner query is executed only once. It finds a group identifier `(exercise, rep)` tuple and a corresponding maximum `kg` group value. 
Then inner query is joined with `Test` table in order to get "content" of rows (in your case only one additional field `date`).

Overall performance is quit optimal.

You need only to iterate over results of this query.

See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column).

---

Edit:

Exclude multiple `(rep, exercise)` records having same `kg` (almost same result as OP's looping)

```
SELECT kg, rep, exercise, MAX(date) 
FROM 
    (SELECT t.kg, t.rep, t.exercise, t.date
    FROM Test t
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT MAX(kg) as kg, exercise, rep
        FROM Test
        WHERE exerVariName = 'Comp'
        GROUP BY exercise, rep) i
    ON t.exercise = i.exercise AND t.rep = i.rep AND t.kg = i.kg
    WHERE t.exerVariName = 'Comp') t
GROUP BY t.kg, t.rep, t.exercise
```

Comment: I'm testing these out right now, I see that I need to learn more about joins because I dont understand the code haha, however, these two different queries result in different things, the later one showing like half the amount of rows, but I'm not sure which one is the correct one yet, I'd like to loop out `exercise` as well so I can see what is what to determine whether its correct or not, if you'd like to help out with that!

Comment: Okey, so I managed to display the exercise number and compare it to the results of my old query/for loop code and when `exercise` is 2 or 3 it got all the correct results, however when it was 1, it only showed 4 out of 6 results that my query showed, can't figure out why :/

Comment: What *'my query'* are you talking about? As I can see you `getPR` query may return at most 1 result. You say your query returned 6.

Comment: I'll update my post and include a picture to compare

Comment: @Pontus Svedberg, you may have different results for queries in case of some rows with `rep` or `exercise` columns are `NULL`.

Comment: There are no `NULL` values in my database :/ cant really see whats the problem since I'm pretty sure this would solve my problem!

Comment: @Pontus Svedberg, let's go to [chat](https://niltalk.com/r/m4PxE) to discuss. Password - **stackoverflow**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135416/discussion-between-ivan-gritsenko-and-pontus-svedberg).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT kg, rep, date, exercise, rep FROM Test test1 WHERE rep = (SELECT TOP 1 test2.rep FROM Test test2 WHERE test2.exercise = test1.exercise AND test2.rep = test1.rep ORDER BY kg DESC) GROUP BY exercise, rep
```

Loop over those results and display them.

Comment: resulted in this `There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 66,Token in error = SELECT ]`